we are running into "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type" issues but from what we can see the code seems right?
We have been recently doing an upgrade from .NET 4.8 to .NET 8.0. We have started on our dependency injection using our Identity controller however are running into errors

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[ProActiveV2.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'ProActiveV2.Controllers.AccountController'

This is stopping the program from running. We have tried a lot of different solution but currently have had no luck.
The error: https://i.sstatic.net/pBSW3K5f.png
Our program.cs file:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ProActiveV2.DAL;
using ProActiveV2.Models;
using ProActiveV2.Utilities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Yarp.ReverseProxy;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProActiveContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProActiveContext")));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProActiveContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddScoped<Utility>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

AccountController:
namespace ProActiveV2.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly Utility utility;
        private readonly ProActiveContext db;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        // Constructor injecting dependencies
        public AccountController(
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            Utility _utility,
            ProActiveContext context,
            IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration
)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            utility = _utility;
            db = context;
            _environment = environment;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
    }
}

ApplicationUser class:
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ProActiveV2.DAL;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProActiveV2.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : ProActiveContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProActiveContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}


It shows UserManager<ApplicationUser> is registered incorrectly. You are scaffolding with a new dbconext ProActiveContext, please share. when does this error occur, upon project started or when entering controller endpoitns?

The error usually occurs when I start the program but it looks to be when it tries to ender the first controller endpoint

It is not a minimal reproducible example. Judging from the error message the user is registered incorrectly and the references or namespaces might have been used incorrectly. Please provide more debug information and the left context code.
